# What the difference between a.b and a->b in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

A requirement of A.B is that A must declare @synthesize before using the setter or getter
but A->B doesn't require this.

I don't understand which is better and what one uses the least amount of memory?

If I convert from A.B to A->B will it use less memory or the same amount?
A->B uses less memory because you don't need to declare @synthesize, right?

Comment: @peoro: Objective-C is related to C (and, less so, C++). It would make sense to leave the tags there.

Comment: @BoltClock: this question contains some objective-c specific things (like `@synthesize`). Besides any C question would be related to Objective C and to C++ (a little less); let's alias these three tags then...

Comment: The dynamics of `.` and `->` for Objective C properties are different enough from C and C++ that I think those tags should be removed.  The current C and C++ answers are incorrect for Objective C.

Comment: There is no need for either @synthesize or @property for `a.b` to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is an Objective-C object then `a.b = c;` is the same as to write `[a setB:c];`.

`setB:` in this case is a default name for automatic generated setter method when you are specifying `@property (...) typeB b;` and `@synthesize b`. Instead of `...` you can place corresponding memory specifier, as retain, assign, copy.
By writing `a->b = c` you avoid using setter method, and access `b` directly.

So, construction `a->b` generates less extra-code but breaks one of the major OOP notion of "Encapsulation" and you also should handle memory related staff manually.

For example if you've specified `retain` in `b`'s `@property`, then construction `a.b = c` will behave almost in the same fashion as `a->b = [c retain]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged C too, a->b and a.b access the same element (b) of the structure (a), but in the first case a is a pointer to a structure, while in the second a is a structure itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a case of one being better than the other. They do different things.

If you declare a property (i.e., an `@property` and a `@synthesize` or `@dynamic`), then the compiler will generate getters and setters for you, both using the standard Objective-C naming conventions.

a->b is actually a C construct. It can be used in Objective-C but is much less common. Perhaps the easiest way to explain is with the following code:

```
typedef struct { int a; int b; } someType;

someType a;
someType* b;

// assign values 
a.a = 1;
a.b = 2;

// also assign values (assume memory has been allocated)
b->a = 1;
b->b = 2;
```

(This is from memory. There may be typos.)

Comment: can you tell me if i convert from a.b into a->b is that will use less memory or it not change?

Answer (score 0):

```
a.b => member b of object a
a->b => member b of object pointed by a
```

In first memory to object `a` is allocated on stack. In the second case, memory for the object that `a` is pointing to is given from free store.

Note: Since your question tagged C++.

Answer (score 0):

if a is a struct use a.b

if a is a pointer to a struct use a->b

if a is an object pointer and b is a ivar use a->b

if a is an object pointer and b is a property use a.b